# What is the most common usage of enums in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style, enums

What is the correct way, the most common, of using enums in Java?
Given I need to use enumeration in let's say class constructor or factory method parameter, the first thing I can think of is to include public static `enum` inside my class, and import it.

```java
package mypackage;
import mypackage.Data.ContentType;

class Data {
  public static enum ContentType { TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3 }  

  ContentType type;
  String value;

  public Data( String value, ContentType type ) {
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

Example usage: `new Data( "some value", ContentType.TYPE1 );`.

What is the reason people prefer using construction like the one below?

```
public static final int TYPE1 = 1;
public static final int TYPE2 = 2;
public static final int TYPE3 = 3;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: [Edited - disregard comment]

Comment: Look up the `TimeUnit` enum and how it's used with the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: That's not a great example; that's an ugly but useful hack.

Comment: enums are used when you have an attribute that takes its values in a fixed and closed set. Example: a playing card can be {SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS}

Comment: @Nambari , sorry the code in tutorial at oracle is not even close to real world example

Comment: @SLaks: I'm sure you know more about it than me. Why is it an ugly hack?

Comment: @user2622016: Well, if you read the text (not just code), you may get some clues.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: Because that's not what an enum is supposed to mean.

Comment: @SLaks: I thought they were now the preferred way of writing singletons since their creation. You've given me food for thought!

Comment: Unfortunately in Polish, there is a really nice explanation for uses from the simplest to some complex examples [here](http://javastart.pl/zaawansowane-programowanie/enum/). Maybe I'll translate it to English, it would be a nice addition to this post.

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to call this a "common" usage, but enums are great for making [some kinds of state machines](https://gist.github.com/cky/3392271).

Answer (score 1):

Good question. An `Enum` would be best used for:

1. A **fixed** set of data that would never ever change. Such as months names, weekdays..etc
2. It's very useful to protect against typing mistakes in strings. You may mistype `Januar` if you type it multiple times, but with an `Enum`, it's syntactically checked.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use enums for current state of object, useful when you want to implement FSM
2. As njzk said in comment, enum allows you to create A fixed set of data
3. limit yourself to simple enums, dont forget they can have parameters, and methods

consider something like that (maybe not useful in real world example, but its for showing you some functionality)

```
public enum Operations{ ADD,SUB,...;
 public int execute(int a, int b)
 {
    switch(this)
    {
    case ADD:
     return a+b;
    case SUB:
     return a-b;
         ....
        }
 }
}
```

now you can have method

```
public int execute(Operations op,int a, int b)
{
return op.execute(a,b);
}
```

which returns you different result, for different value of enum

Answer (score 0):

Using enums offers a clear set of advantages since the compiler checks for you if any one is missing in a switch statement, and no values outside of the declared ones can be used.

Some people may keep using constants out of inertia or because their code may be compiled into other languages. Mostly it is because they have not encountered enums, and in most cases, Enum is better than those constants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I declared as Enum and a few reasons on that below:

> 1. Objects which contain Award references through composition do not need to create a new Award object each time one is added to it (Read
>      on using Enums vs using Singletons).
> 2. Since Enums are instance controlled, I can use == operator instead of .equals() when I need to compare Awards, and save myself a
>      (miserable) bit of CPU time.
> 3. So overall, use Enums when you have a chance to  reuse existing immutable objects out of a set instead of creating new ones.

```
public enum Award {
    /*List of possible awards */
    FIRST_AWARD("FIRST_AWARD", "FIRST_AWARD_IN_THE_LIST", "./firstAward.jpg"),
    SECOND_AWARD("SECOND_AWARD", "SECOND_AWARD_IN_THE_LIST", "./secondAward.jpg"),
    THIRD_AWARD("THIRD_AWARD", "THIRD_AWARD_IN_THE_LIST", "./thirdAward.jpg");      

    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final String imageLink; 

    Award (String name, String description, String imageLink){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
    }

...
}
```